# Trying to create a Ruby script. I want to append Strings containing commands to a file

Tags: ruby

```
mysqldump = "mysqldump"
`#{mysqldump} > backup_file.sql`
```

I'm supposed to append several of those mysqldump Strings (I simplified it for this example; normally line 2 would have the username and password as options) into the SQL file.

The problem is line 2, when I try to call the Bash operator '>' to append the String. Instead of appending, the script ends up calling the mysqldump command itself.

What can I do to store the String "mysqldump" into the file backup_file.sql? I want to do it the same way as line 2: automatically appending through the Bash.

Comment: did you mean `echo #{mysqldump} > backup_file.sql`?

Comment: @BroiSatse is correct about your needing `echo`. I would add that the append operator in bash is `>>`, not `>`; the `>` operator will overwrite the entire contents of `backup_file.sql` every time you use it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, create a .sql file with the contents of multiple schemas? Or create a  file containing multiple commands itself? Maybe use something other than the name of the variable as a value in your example?

Comment: @Broi Yes, I want to do something like echo. But I can't call echo from within Ruby; it doesn't exist. Do I need to use backticks somewhere or something I'm missing?

Comment: You are already backticking it so it will be send to your system, so yes, you can use echo. :)

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins Create a file with multiple commands. I have a hash and a loop.The loop gets several usernames and passwords from the hash. Then several "mysqldump -u #{username} -p #{password}" commands are supposed to be stored as Strings in the SQL file.

Comment: @Broi The echo worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to append "like" you said and not overwrite the target file use `>>` instead of `>` . Here is a working version of your script:

```
za$ emacs ./foo.rb

#!/usr/bin/env ruby

target_dir = "/Users/za/ruby-practice/backup_file.sql"

mysqldump = "mysqldump"
`echo #{mysqldump} >> "#{target_dir}"`
```

You can also do something like :  `system %Q{echo "#{mysqldump}" >> "#{target_dir}"}` 
. Personally , I would say use [IO#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) instead of making system calls inside your script , if you want a pure ruby solution/system independent solution.

Comment: You're right. This is generally what I was looking for, and echo is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use pure ruby to do it? Like:

```
File.open("backup_file.sql", "w") do |f|
  dump_lines.each do |line|
    f.puts line
  end
end
```

assuming that you have the dump in an array..

Comment: That could work, but I was following an example, and they were using the more simpler way.